# No SQLite in use but I get an "android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException" Exception

Tags: android, sqlite, exception

I'm using BugSense to track down errors in my app, and it just caught one related to SQLite... the problem is that I don't use SQLite. I use sharedPreferences and ads though, but no SQLite at all...

Why is this happening? Bad SD card or no space?
Should I surround the sharedPreferences code with a try catch block just in case?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDiskIOException: disk I/O error
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.native_setLocale(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setLocale(SQLiteDatabase.java:2074)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1014)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:962)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1043)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1036)
at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:771)
at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:215)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.initDatabase(WebViewDatabase.java:227)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.init(WebViewDatabase.java:209)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase.access$000(WebViewDatabase.java:38)
at android.webkit.WebViewDatabase$1.run(WebViewDatabase.java:190)
```

And more data from BugSense:

[image]

Comment: It looks like a WebView uses SQLite internally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

You are using a `WebView`, and it uses SQLite under the covers (for its cache IIRC). As to why you are getting a disk I/O error, that's difficult to say with any certainty, given the info in front of you.

> Bad SD card or no space?

`WebView` will store its database on internal storage, so it won't be a bad SD card.

Being out of internal storage is certainly possible.

> Should I surround the sharedPreferences code with a try catch block just in case?

Since this has nothing to do with your `SharedPreferences`, I doubt that it will help.

Moreover, unless you see this occurring a lot, I would assume it is a device-specific problem (e.g., out of internal storage).

Comment: Oh, I see you are right, I do use a WebView... So there is anything I could do?

Comment: @Deses: Again, unless you see this occurring a lot, I would assume it is a device-specific problem (e.g., out of internal storage). There is nothing you can do directly.

Comment: Okay then, thank you! I hope I don't get rated 1 star because of that. People is really unforgiving.

Comment: If the app is stored on the SD Card, would the WebView still store its db on internal storage?

Comment: @aimango: Yes, because data is always stored on internal storage. The old install-to-SD stuff only referred to APK contents.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you using more than 2 webviews inside the same window, SQLiteDiskIOException may happen. So it is recommended that just use single webview in your activity